# Как заполнить разреженную матрицу на 95% нулями?

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Мне необходимо заполнить разреженную матрицу на 95% нулями.

Как это сделать?

Пока сделал просто заполнение матрицы случайным образом нулями и единицами. Вручную вводить каждый элемент не хочется.

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 10))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь [np.random.choice()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=random%20choice#numpy.random.choice):

```
a = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(10,10), p=(.95, .05))
```

---

Результат:

```
In [8]: a
Out[8]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [9]: a.sum()
Out[9]: 5
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы сразу дать ссылку на оф.док..

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю можно ли сделать это в одну строчку, но можно так

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=(10, 10))
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j] <= 95:
            a[i][j] = 0
        else:
            a[i][j] = 1

print(a)
```

Или еще есть вариант использовать обычный random а не numpy.random